# Problem while ng build using the new angular 17 application builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ng-build, angular17

ng serve is working fine, but ng build is giving this error.

> X [ERROR] Could not resolve "path"
>
> ```
> (disabled):node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:3:21:
>   3 │ const path = require("path");
>     ╵                      ~~~~~~
> ```
>
> The package "path" wasn't found on the file system but is built into
> node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform:
> 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.
>
> X [ERROR] Could not resolve "fs"
>
> ```
> (disabled):node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:4:19:
>   4 │ const fs = require("fs").promises;
>     ╵                    ~~~~
> ```
>
> The package "fs" wasn't found on the file system but is built into
> node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform:
> 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.
>
> X [ERROR] Could not resolve "url"
>
> ```
> node_modules/http-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:40:38:
>   40 │ const url_1 = __importDefault(require("url"));
>      ╵                                       ~~~~~
> ```
>
> The package "url" wasn't found on the file system but is built into
> node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform:
> 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.
>
> X [ERROR] Could not resolve "child_process"
>
> ```
> node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:6:12:
>   6 │ } = require("child_process");
>     ╵             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> The package "child_process" wasn't found on the file system but is
> built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use
> "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.

ng build is working fine with old build system

I tried adding

```
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "net": false,
    "tls": false,
    "url": false,
    "http": false,
    "path": false,
    "util": false,
    "zlib": false,
    "https": false,
    "assert": false,
    "stream": false,
    "child_process": false   }
```

to package.json but it did not work.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-new-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "prepare": "husky"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{md,html}": [],
    "*.{js,jsx,mjs,cjs,ts,tsx,json}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-community/csv-export": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-community/styles": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/core": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/menu": "^30.0.3",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model": "^30.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^17.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.8",
    "@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.5.7",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-thin-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^12.0.4",
    "@ngneat/tailwind": "^7.0.3",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^17.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.11",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.29",
    "angular-google-tag-manager": "^1.9.0",
    "atatus-spa": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "dexie": "^3.2.4",
    "fabric": "^5.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intro.js": "^7.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.29",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.5",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-image-zoom": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^16.2.3",
    "pusher-js": "^8.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "signature_pad": "^4.1.5",
    "stripe-angular": "^1.9.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "tslib": "^2.6.0",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.16",
    "workbox-core": "^7.0.0",
    "workbox-precaching": "^7.0.0",
    "workbox-routing": "^7.0.0",
    "workbox-strategies": "^7.0.0",
    "workbox-window": "^7.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.8",
    "@ngrx/eslint-plugin": "^17.0.1",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^17.0.1",
    "@schematics/angular": "^17.0.8",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/fabric": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.53.4",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.8",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.1",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.2.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "cypress": "^13.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^43.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.15.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "husky": "^9.0.6",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^13.1.4",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.0",
    "local-web-server": "^5.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.25",
    "prettier": "3.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.88.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-cli": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "got": "^12.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "@koa/cors": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "*************************",
    "schematicCollections": ["@angular-eslint/schematics", "@ngrx/schematics"]
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-new-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["fabric", "jspdf-autotable"],
            "outputPath": {
              "base": "public",
              "browser": ""
            },
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": ["src/polyfills.ts"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/.well-known",
              "src/version.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "./node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.css",
              "././src/assets/style_varients/fonts/fontAwesome/css/all.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["././src/assets/style_varients"]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.js"
            ],
            "browser": "src/main.ts"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "sourceMap": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "17mb",
                  "maximumError": "19mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "17mb",
                  "maximumError": "19mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "angular-new-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "angular-new-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "angular-new-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.html"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:application": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    },
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:library": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try again before building the the project do the - `npm install -f` and make sure delete the `node_module`

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ I deleted the node_modules and ran npm install -f. But that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please share your `package.json` & `angular.json` file here or if you have github source code will be great

Comment: I have shared package.json and angular.json for your reference @Ｒの卄ＩＴ

Comment: "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-thin-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
---------
something wrong these packages - Do one thing create an another branch and on that branch remove these package then build your project it will work perfectly. then you can deal with these packages after that

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ You get error with the fontawesome because of not having .npmrc file. I have that.

Comment: Can you check what is pulling `jsdom` with `npm ls jsdom ` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler fabric@5.3.0 and jest-environment-jsdom@29.7.0 are pulling jsdom. I removed those packages and replaced fabric with browser compatible version. But still the issue remains. npm ls jsdom is still giving the same response as before removing the packages. The response for npm ls jsdom is given below.
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.1.3
│ └─┬ jest-environment-jsdom@29.7.0
│   └── jsdom@20.0.3
└─┬ fabric@5.3.0
  └── jsdom@19.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and it seems to be due to fabric having a browser and non-browser version.

Check this thread:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/54235

But TL;DR, update your packe.json from `"fabric": "^5.3.0"` to `"fabric": "5.3.0-browser"` delete node_modules an lock and run `npm i` again before building.

Comment: This helped. For me jest was also causing problem. Running npm ls jsdom as @Matthieu Riegler said helped me find the issue. I removed jest, updated fabric like you said and now it is working fine. I don't know if there is a browser version of jest. Until I find one I have to continue without jest.